# SP2013: Search results "View Library" link incorrect

Tags: search, 2013

I've an issue with my SP2013 installation.
It's a single server installation on system named "internal".
I've added an AAM for

- Default (`http://external.com`) (required for an anonymous site collection)
- Internet (`https://external.com`) (ssl url for document management site col)
- Custom (`http://internal`)

My search content source is set to `http://internal`.
The search results looking good, every URL is correct **but** the link "View Library" within the hover panel links to `http://internal/...`.
I've also added a "server name mapping" for `http://internal` to `https://external.com`, but that one is not changing (even after a full crawl).

Any idea, how to change this behavior, so that also the "View Library" link is working on the internet https domain?

Setting the content source to the `https://external.com` url throws an exception that it cannot be accessed by the crawler account.

Comment: No one with an idea?

Comment: I to am having the exact same problem and have tried the same solutions, any ideas yet? -Eric Niemiec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by myself.
I've added https://external.com to the content source (as the only content source). Then added the site to the "local intranet" zone in Internet Explorer and added the domain "external.com" to the hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1.
And now the "magic trick": [Disable the loopback check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us) (if not already done).
You can then test it by opening the https url in Internet Explorer on the SharePoint server. If you can successfully login with the content access account, everything is ok.